# Equivalent 'rep' of R in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, rep

I have searched for some similar questions like'equivalent R function rep in Python'.

In R,rep can be used to an array or a dataframe and you can set the parameter `each` to specify whether you want to repeat every element or repeat the whole list/dataframe.

But in Python, you have to distinguish between array and dataframe.

For an array, `np.repeat` will repeat each element and `np.tile` repeat the whole array .

```
x=['a','b']

np.repeat(x,2)#repeat each element twice
Out[85]: array(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], dtype='<U1')

np.tile(x,2)#repeat the whole array twice
Out[86]: array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], dtype='<U1')
```

For a Pandas dataframe. `pd.concat` can be used to repeat the whole dataframe:

```
d=pd.DataFrame({'x':['a','b'],'y':['c','d']})
d
Out[94]: 
   x  y
0  a  c
1  b  d


pd.concat([d]*2)
Out[93]: 
   x  y
0  a  c
1  b  d
0  a  c
1  b  d
```

My question is how to repeat each row in a pandas dataframe rather repeat it as a whole. The result I want is:

```
x y
a c
a c
b d 
b d
```

Anyway, I wish there is a function in Python like'rep' which can be used to both list and dataframe , and also can specify repeat as a whole or repeat each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `pandas` you can using `reindex` with `np.repeat`

```
d.reindex(np.repeat(df.index.values,2))
   x  y
0  a  c
0  a  c
1  b  d
1  b  d
```

---

Or re-build your dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(d.values,2,axis=0),columns=d.columns)
   x  y
0  a  c
1  a  c
2  b  d
3  b  d
```

Also `concat` wih `sort_index`

```
pd.concat([d]*2).sort_index()
   x  y
0  a  c
0  a  c
1  b  d
1  b  d
```

Comment: `d.reindex(np.repeat(df.index.values,2))` this one is way faster. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [np.repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [np.arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
In [183]: d.iloc[np.repeat(np.arange(len(d)), 2)]
Out[183]: 
   x  y
0  a  c
0  a  c
1  b  d
1  b  d
```